# Why in a RC circuit is the resistance multiplied by the capacitance equal to the time constant (inverse of the exponential growth rate)

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits

The first three sections of this question ("Background", "Terms", and "Description of a capacitor’s charge over time in a direct current RC circuit") builds up the relevant information needed to understand my question which is located in the "My Question" section. For this post it will be assumed you have a basic understanding of calculus and how a direct current RC circuit behaves.

Note: I have looked at related questions on this site and others and I still do not have a clear answer to my question.

### Background Info

**Background 1:** We know that the derivative of an exponential function (for now on I will refer to exponential functions as “exp functions”) is simply the exp function itself multiple by some constant. In English, we can say that the derivative of the exp function is proportional to the exp function by some ratio.

[image]

Above is this formally described, and we can see the $k_n$ is simply the ratio between the exp function and the derivative of the exp function that makes them proportional. I like to call $k_n$ the **exponential’s growth rate**

**Background 2:** Euler’s number is the only base $n$ such that $k_n$(described above) is equal to 1. This simply means that the exp function with Euler’s number as the base is the only function in math that is equal to its own derivative.

[image]

**Background 3:** Using a logarithmic identity, the chain rule of derivatives, the identities above, and some algebra, we can prove the following: (I will not include the proof to keep this post less lengthy)

[image]

What the above identity means is that using Euler’s number, we can represent a given exp function from its growth rate ($k_n$ – described above) rather than using the base of the exp function itself. In English, we can say that we can describe an exp function based on how fast it changes, **this is very import to understand for the rest of this post**. We can also say that $k_n$ is positively correlated to how fast the exponential function changes. So an exp function with a higher $k_n$ will grow much faster (visa versa).

### Terms

**Exponential Growth Rate:** The exponential growth rate will simply be defined as $k_n$ which was described above. For the rest of this post I will refer to $k_n$ as the exponential growth rate.

**Exponential Growth Factor:** The exponential growth factory is simply the base of an exp function, which was described as $n$ above. I wont use this term much is this post but be aware this is different then the exponential growth rate.

### Description of a capacitor’s charge over time in a direct current RC circuit:

Now we are ready to actually talk about calculating the voltage in a RC reactive circuit. From what I understand a reactive component is simple a component whose response to a change in either voltage or current is a function of time. We know that in a RC circuit, the change of a capacitor’s voltage over time (from when the input voltage was changed) is equal to the following equation:

[image]

Essential this function will exponentially grow from the initial voltage to the final voltage but it will asymptotically approach the final voltage. This makes sense since the exponential function is in the denominator of the above fraction.

I want to describe the role of the time constant ($\tau$) and Euler’s number in the RC circuit equation above. The expression $e^{\frac{x}{\tau}}$ is equivalent to the following:

[image]

"Background 3" in the above “Background” section showed that $n^t=e^{k_n t}$, this simply means Euler’s number is just being used to represent a given exponential function based off its exponential growth rate (see "Terms" section above). There are many questions online trying to figure out what is the specific role of Euler’s number in this RC circuit equation, but the way I see it is just being used as a way to represent a exponential functional based of the exponential growth rate rather than its exponential growth factor. This makes since it would be easier in this case to describe the system (RC circuit) based on how quickly it changes. Since the time constant is equal to RC, we can see the exponential growth rate is equal to the following:

[image]

Simply the time constant is the inverse of the exponential growth rate of the exp function used to model the RC circuit. In English, as the time constant rises, the rate of which the exp function used to model the RC circuit will increase slower. To show what I mean, consider the following two capacitors charge over time where the time constant equals 1 and where the time constant equals 5.

[image]

Notice how when the time constant equals 1, the capacitor charges up much faster than when the time constant equals a higher value of 5. This makes perfect since the time constant is the inverse of the exponential growth rate $k_n$. It also makes intuitive since that a capacitor with a larger capacitance would have a larger time constant and thus a lower exponential growth rate (a lower $k_n$), which in turn means it will take longer to charge up.
I understand that typically the time constant  is defined as the time it takes for the capacitor to charge $63.212… $% of its final value. This is because when the time equals the time constant you essential have $1-e^{-1}$, which equals $0.63212…$ This is equally valid way of looking at the time constant but for the sake of my question I thinks easier to look at **the time constant as simply the inverse of the exponential growth rate of the exp function used to model the RC circuit.**

### My Question:

We know that a series RC circuit with an 1 Ohm resistor and a 1 µ Farad capacitor will produce a time constant of 1. This essential means that exponential growth rate of the exp function used to model the RC circuit is 1. In other words we would be simply modeling the RC circuit with the following:

[image]

If we had a situation where the capacitance was larger we would have a larger time constant and thus a lower exponential growth rate.  We would then model the RC circuit with

[image]

I understand that if the exceptional growth rate is 1 than the RC circuit is being modeled with Euler’s number and thus after one time constant has passed, the capacitor will be about 63% of its final charge. I even understand why the resistance times the capacitance would be inversely proportional to the exponential growth rate. My Question is why is a RC circuit with a 1 Ohm resistor and 1 Farad capacitor modeled with an exponential function with an exponential growth rate of 1? I do understand that Ohms multiple by Farads cancels out to be seconds. Specifically, I am wondering how we figured out that a RC circuit with a 1 Ohm resistor and 1 Farad happens to have a exponential growth rate of 1 and not some other growth rate.

### My Possible Answer:

1. We understand that the charge of a capacitor in a RC circuit will exponentially grow with a rate of growth that will decrease as time goes on. In addition, the capacitors charge will asymptotically approach a single value
2. With the description of the system above we than built an equation that has the above attributes as a function of time. This equation is the following:

[image]

3. Then experimentally found a specific resistance and capacitance (1 Ohm and 1 Farad) such that the charge of the capacitor was 63.212…% of its final value after one second. This implies the system with that resistance/capacitance can be modeled with an exp function that has an exceptional growth rate of 1 in respect to seconds. We then assumed that the expositional growth rate grows linearly to the inverse of the resistance multiplied by capacitance and that the only variables that would determine the systems exceptional growth rate was the resistance and the capacitance. Because of these assumptions, we can now define the time constant as R x C. This would essentially mean the time constant for a RC circuit was calculated by an experiment. **If this is true, I feel I would now have a full understand of where the time constant in RC circuit comes from.**

Comment: This should be a lot shorter. You want to know (i) a relevant differential equation and (ii) how to show $e^{-t/(RC)}$ appears in its solutions, and that's it.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit#Time-domain_considerations).

Comment: For 1 micro-farad capacitor in series with 1 ohm resistor the time constant is not 1 but 1 micro-second.

Comment: Seems a little odd I am being down voted for the length of this post when I was attempting to be as clear as possible. A simple "you should shorten this" would of been helpful without a downvote. I have not worked with differential equations so maybe its impossible for me to get a answer to my question until I do? @J.G.

Comment: @nasu Thanks for catching my mistake

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I didn't downvote. At least own downvote predates my advice.

Comment: for any satisfying answer you need to be able to truly understand the differential equation that this is derived from

Comment: Yes, it does lol @J.G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the circuit voltage be $V_0$. The charge $Q$ on the capacitor satisfies the differential equation $R\dot{Q}+Q/C=V_0$ (because the current across the resistor is $I=\dot{Q}$), which has solution $Q=CV_0(1-e^{-t/(RC)})$. The voltage drop across the capacitor is then $Q/C=V_0(1-e^{-t/(RC)})$. You can derive this in the continuous limit from a difference equation $R\frac{Q_{n+1}-Q_n}{\Delta t}+Q/C=V_0$, where $Q_n$ is $Q(n\Delta t)$, provided you use a limit-based definition of $e$. But it's better to just learn [the expected technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_factor#Solving_first_order_linear_ordinary_differential_equations) (which unfortunately uses $Q,\,R$ to mean unrelated quantities).